# Recover Bitmap from Grayscale to Original

Tags: android

I have a bitmap which I make it grayscale using this code :

```
 grayscale.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                   BitmapDrawable  abmp = (BitmapDrawable)img.getDrawable();
                   bmp = abmp.getBitmap();
                          operation= Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(),
                          bmp.getHeight(),bmp.getConfig());
                          Canvas c = new Canvas(operation);
                          Paint paint = new Paint();
                          ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
                          cm.setSaturation(0);
                          ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
                          paint.setColorFilter(f);
                          c.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);
                          img.setImageBitmap(operation);
            }
          });
```

I want to recover it to its original form.. Can someone help me plz?

Comment: `BitmapDrawable  abmp = (BitmapDrawable)img.getDrawable();`

Comment: While you can convert a colorful image to grayscale, you can't **recolor** a desaturated image to its original colors. You must have a copy of the original image.

Comment: my image is taken from camera and putted in an imageView :
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     
     switch(requestCode){
     case 0:
         if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
           Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            img.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
             }
     }
 }

Answer (score 0):

to set the grayscale try:

```
Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();

        if (drawable != null) {
            ColorMatrix grayMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
            grayMatrix.setSaturation(0);
            ColorMatrixColorFilter grayScaleFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(
                    grayMatrix
            );
            drawable.setColorFilter(grayScaleFilter);
        }
```

instead of setting it on paint. then to remove:

```
Drawable d = img.getDrawable();

if(d != null){
    d.setColorFilter(null);
}
```

Comment: sorry but it does not make it grayscale

Comment: it's weird, i'm using the exact same code and it's working perfectly